# How do you enable mod_rewrite on any OS?

Tags: mod-rewrite, php

If I understand correctly, I need to put something in `httpd.config` to enable mod_rewrite. If this is true, what do I need to put in `httpd.conf` or `apache.conf`? Please be OS specific.

Comment: Check the answer by @FarmerGedden
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16814691/4061061

Comment: It's not possible to ask this for any operating system. This is a misconception usually coming from Microsoft Windows users, that only used Microsoft Windows, and they are used to install .exe software without caring about much details.
There are installation details and are incredibly important from distribution to distribution, from philosophical, technical and security reasons. Please clarify your operating system to make this question answerable :) Nobody can answer covering Windows, macOS, Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, FreeBSD, and 30.000 other GNU/Linux distributions. Chose one :) Thx

Comment: Also, this question is part of the PHP collective for no particular reason to me. Can we unlink? Also, this is tagged PHP. We should remove the PHP Tag to avoid well-known incredible confusion to newcomers, since the installation of "mod_rewrite" is clearly not related to PHP but Apache HTTPd server. They are sometime bundled together, but that does not make mod_rewrite a PHP thing.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Nope, `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module and has nothing to do with PHP.

To activate the module, the following line in `httpd.conf` needs to be active:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to see whether it is already active, try putting a `.htaccess` file into a web directory containing the line

```
RewriteEngine on
```

if this works without throwing a 500 internal server error, and the `.htaccess` file gets parsed, URL rewriting works.

Comment: Thanks... how do I tell if the .htaccess file is getting parsed?

Comment: @John you usually can't activate mod_rewrite yourself on shared hosting: It's up to the hosting company to do so. Try `RewriteEngine` to see whether it maybe already is active - if it isn't, you're going to have to talk to them.

Comment: @John re your updated comment: Write something like `asdfasdf` into the file. That should land you a `500 internal server error`.

Comment: Yeah, okay.  It is getting parsed.  I still can get even a simple ReWrite to work, though.

Comment: @John does it accept `RewriteEngine On` without errors? If it does, the problem is with your rewrite statement. Maybe worth a new question.

Answer (score 62):

Just a fyi for people enabling mod_rewrite on Debian with Apache2:

**To check whether mod_rewrite is enabled:**

Look in mods_enabled for a link to the module by running

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep rewrite
```

If this outputs `rewrite.load` then the module is enabled. (Note: your path to apache2 may not be /etc/, though it's likely to be.)

**To enable mod_rewrite if it's not already**:

Enable the module (essentially creates the link we were looking for above):

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Reload all apache config files:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed when troubleshooting a permalink Wordpress issue.  Thanks for specific SSH commands I needed.

Comment: Just the perfect answer!

Answer (score 14):

In my case, issue was occured even after all these configurations have done (@Pekka has mentioned changes in httpd.conf & .htaccess files). It was resolved only after I add

```
<Directory "project/path">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to virtual host configuration in vhost file

Edit on 29/09/2017 (For Apache 2.4 <)
 [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9117898/219112)

```
<VirtualHost dropbox.local:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/Documenten/Dropbox/Dropbox/dummy-htdocs"
ServerName dropbox.local
ErrorLog "logs/dropbox.local-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dropbox.local-access.log" combined
<Directory "E:/Documenten/Dropbox/Dropbox/dummy-htdocs">
    # AllowOverride All      # Deprecated
    # Order Allow,Deny       # Deprecated
    # Allow from all         # Deprecated

    # --New way of doing it
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

Comment: the update seems to be missing the part I needed `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it should stay more in topic with the question that was very generic, about "any OS". Instead, this answer is about a vertical edge case on Microsoft Windows with Dropbox. Please drop any line mentioning Dropbox. Also because promoting Dropbox in a snippet with no reason, may be confused with spam.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not need to. `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module. It has nothing to do with `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

if it related to hosting site then ask to your hosting or if you want to enable it in local machine then check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enabling rewrite module in wamp apache 
https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s 
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and check the rewrite module option
it should be checked but after that wamp require restart all services

Answer (score 0):

Module rewrite_module is built-in in to the server most cases

Use .htaccess

Use the Mod Rewrite Generator at http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: This answer is not clarifying. If OP is asking how to enable something, you're expected to assume it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

network solutions offers the advice to put a php.ini in the cgi-bin to enable mod_rewrite

Comment: I've heard this, too, but I think it's false. I recommend just checking the syntax of your .htaccess file to screen out any errors. Pretty much any server, including Netsol's, that run Apache have mod_rewrite enabled by default.

Answer (score -3):

In order to use mod_rewrite you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
 $ su

 $ passwd **********

 # a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
 # service apache2 restart

 # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
 # service apache2 restart
```