# Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am having trouble removing index.php from my URLs in Codeigniter. I've made a few websites with Codeigniter 1.7 and the .htaccess code I used doesn't work in 2.

I have tried using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I've also tried it without RewriteBase / in.

I have changed the $config['uri_protocol'] to REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING and nothing.

I have set $config['index_page'] = "";

The file structure is 192.168.0.130/(site)/ so it must be going back to the root of the server and can't find the index.php file.

All of the controllers I have made can be reached by putting 192.168.0.130/(site)/index.php/testcontroller

Thank you.

Apologies if this has been asked before - I have looked and tried what I could see.

Edit:

I should also add that I changed the default folders to be

application

CI-2.0

index.php

and changed the paths in index.php to be correct.

Comment: Do you have any htaccess files in the parent folder?

Comment: There is a htaccess file. It only has one line in it and it's for a different project - I just tried commenting it out but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Btw: The system and application RewriteConds have to start with /SUBFOLDER/

Comment: I tried adding the subfolder but still nothing. I've also edited the post to say that I changed the default folder name for system to CI-2.0.

Comment: `192.168.0.130/(site)` is (site) `root`/contains your index.php? else you will need to add the directory to `Rewrite Base`.

Comment: I have tried adding both /192.168.0.130/site/ and /site/ for Rewritebase and I still get the error.

Comment: if server is windows use webconfig file instead of htacces

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the first code block you posted, but instead of /index.php try using /(site)/index.php (obv replacing (site) with whatever your site folder is named).

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. This is going to turn out to be something stupid I've missed... Thank you for the help.

Comment: I just moved it to my local server and it works with these .htaccess settings so it must be a server problem.

Comment: This might sound like a dumb question, but did the server you were originally testing on have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: I just found why this was not working with my local EasyPHP setup... If you are using an alias for your website, you will need to change "RewriteBase /" to "RewriteBase /alias".

Comment: Guys take care of the "RewriteBase"! Put in your subfolder where CodeIgniter is located.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

1. Create your htaccess file
2. Set $config[‘index_page’] to an empty (config.php)
3. string Set $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; (config.php)

This is my htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin   

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Source:

http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/codeigniter-2-htaccess-and-friendly-urls

Comment: Thank you. I did actually get it working fine with the same config I had on the local server and the production server so it must have been issue with the dev server we have.

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried every htaccess code, I dig the Google 5 days and tried every htaccess code sample but every one fail. But, finally this code is working for me after adding 

'RewriteBase /my/base/site/url' in .htaccess code.

Before add above line, when I am try to call my CI controller it was being redirect on localhost wamp page. 

So, I added above code as 'RewriteBase'

//config.php
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

he he.. :) Coooollll!!!!! Robin Morgan and Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This much is only required in root folder add this to .htaccess

Comment: this has been the only htaccess that has worked on both my local (xamp on wamp) and hosted server (lamp)

Answer (score 3):

I was on this for 2 days.. Tried everything possible. I've just came out that you need the following:

TYPE:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

And change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All - This will give access to your .htaccess files

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
```

And also enable mod rewrite on Apache:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite
```

Hope this helps,
Mário

Answer (score 2):

After following all instructions from other people and from this [CodeIgnitor URL documnetation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), don't forget to **restart the server**. I simply forgot to do that and kept trying all other solutions.

Comment: note: some web hosts do not require you to restart the server after updating a .htaccess file. For example, hostgator.com does not require a restart:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/must-i-restart-apache-after-changing-a-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add below code in .htacess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Create .htaccess file in your root folder

```
 RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) Edit application/config/config.php  file in Application folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectName';

 $config['index_page'] = '';         // remove index.php
```

i hope it will work for you