# Removing index.php from codeigniter-2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having problems removing index.php from codeigniter-2. **I remember using the same code before too & it worked perfectly fine, but it is not working on codeigniter-2.**

I have checked the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path) question too, still of no help.

My .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I remember seeing this kind of question before on SO. Just wait till I find it! Till then check my answer below. It would work

Comment: Gotcha!! Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2   Somebody close this question cause I dont have enough rep to do so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `/index.php` with `/site_folder_name/index.php`  everywhere & **be sure that your server supports mod_rewrite**

Your new code should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_folder_name/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_folder_name/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_folder_name/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yup I had this. Didn't post this to keep the question short. If the above problem is solved, this would work too

Answer (score 0):

you have to re-write the .htaccess file for this.

maximum server work with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

in godaddy server i have to write this. sometimes it works with above code in godaddy server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```