# Removing index.php in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I'm having some trouble using Codeigniter2.
Essentially I want to remove the annoying "index.php" from my url so that:

```
    - http://localhost/ci_intro/index.php/site/home

    Becomes

    - http://localhost/ci_intro/home
```

I've followed a couple of the links on Stack Overflow already and have found the following two posts:

[Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

And

[Removing index.php from codeigniter-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016778/removing-index-php-from-codeigniter-2)

However after performing both steps still no joy.

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci_intro/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've ensured that the mod_rewrite module is enable in Apache (I'm using Xampp on Windows) but for some reason it's just not working as i'd expect it to.

I have two views in CodeIgniter2, one called Home and another called About. These two link to each other. The links are as follows:

```
    <a href="home">Home</a><br/>
    <a href="about">About</a>
```

If I go to the root URL of my project:

```
   http://localhost/ci_intro/
```

The index function of the Home page is displayed. That's fine and as expected. However, if I then click either link it redirects to:

```
   http://localhost/ci_intro/home

   or

   http://localhost/ci_intro/about
```

Which produces a 404. However if I then type "site" in the URL, the name of my controller, the links take me through to the correctly loaded views:

```
    http://localhost/ci_intro/site/home

    or

    http://localhost/ci_intro/site/about
```

Is there any known way of bypassing this approach so that the controller,in this case site, is removed from the URL entirely as using site/home or site/about in the links in my view does not appear to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that (but might!).

> ```
> - http://localhost/ci_intro/index.php/site/home
>
> Becomes
>
> - http://localhost/ci_intro/home
> ```

The way CI works, `site` is the controller and `home` is the method or function in the controller you are calling. This allows you to gather respective functionality.

e.g. you could have a home controller and an index method like:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        echo 'I am the home controller index';
    }
}
```

which with a url like `http://example.com/home` (or `http://example.com/index.php/home` before .htaccess is involved) would show a page with the text "I am the home controller index".

Then you can add other functionality to the home controller a'la

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        // http://example.com/home
        echo 'I am the home controller index';
    }

    public function user(){
        // http://example.com/home/user
        echo "I am the user method in the home controller";
    }
}
```

which with a url like `http://example.com/home/user` would show a page with the text "I am the user method in the home controller".

You can also create as many other controllers as you need:

```
class About extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        // http://example.com/about
        echo 'I am the about page!';
    }
}
```

`http://example.com/about` will render a page with the text "I am the about page!"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

is all the .htaccess you should need to remove index.php form the url. It'd live in `/ci_into/.htaccess`

If you really want to use http://example.com/home that works with the site controller, you could use [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand what you mean with regards to removing the controller from the URL as it could potentially lead to a loss of scope during development. However, if this is the case how do I go about linking between my views? If I use site/home or site/about it's fine for the first time I click one of them but the next time around it links to site/site/about.

Comment: Check `$config['base_url']` in application/config.php and set it.

Comment: In this case i'm guessing it's localhost/ci_intro ?

Comment: Well, actually, that's probably not the problem. Issue is that the link href="home" will link to ci_intro/home as expected, but CI is then looking for a home controller which doesnt exist. You could add a route in config/routes.php like `$route['about'] = 'site/about';` and the same for home.

Comment: Is that the standard CodeIgniter approach? Seems very long-winded just to get a couple of links working.

Comment: No! This is the point of my answer. Better to create a `home` controller and an `about` controller :)

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'm following a tutorial just to get to grips with the basics of CI (as I've coded in vanilla PHP for years) and they just seem to put a home and an about function under a class of site which they then use to load the views and models. Are you suggesting I need a new class called About and another called Home?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a rock. If it were me (and I think this is the typical CI way), I would create a controller for each page, so yes. I've updated the answer with example url's and an example `about` controller.

Comment: Great, thanks. That's what made the most sense to me but when I was watching the tutorial and they didn't follow that approach I became a but skeptical. Thankyou very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: The line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` Wasn't working for me, until I removed the / before index.php.  That is: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @BrandonRomano yeah, it depends on where the codeigniter installation is. If it is in a subfolder like the OP's was, you're right, there shouldn't be a slash. If the `.htaccess` is in the webroot, then a forward slash is OK (but not necessary).

Comment: Yup, thanks for specifying the difference, I should have been more explicit in my post of why I changed it.  Thanks for the informative post @stormdrain, I was banging my head into a wall over this issue for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Use routes: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

It will look something like this:

```
$route['home'] = 'site/home';
$route['about'] = 'controllername/about';
```