# finding the correct url for post in codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my `controllers/automation.php` file, I have:

```
class Automation extends CI_Controller {
       // some code here
       public function search() {
           // implementation of the search function
       }
}
```

Now, on my `library.js` file I have:

```
function search()
{
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    $.post('./automation/search', { date : date.toString() },
        function(answer){
            alert(answer);
        }
      );
    return;
}
```

However, firebug shows:

```
POST http://localhost/ci/automation/search 404 Not Found
```

what would be the correct `url` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `http://localhost/ci/index.php?automation/search`. That would be the default if you haven't used .htaccess to modify paths so you don't need index.php.

If that's the case and you want to get rid of index.php in your paths, google will give you plenty of resources. One example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2).

Comment: Almost, but not quite ... now it does not send me anything back from the controller ...