# Want to remove Index.php from Codigniter URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove *index.php* from code igniter URL ,I had created *.htaccess* file and stored it in application folder parallel to index.php and also remove

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

from config.php.

**Code in .htaccess file, which is not working :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /WCPM/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**URL of the project is:**

```
localhost/WCPM/index.php
```

**NOTE**:*Please Don't mark this question as duplicate because I had already tried lots of solution for the same but none of them works for me , so at last I am asking this question here for the solution*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Config.php Change as Follows**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/WCPM/';
```

**And Create *.htaccess* file like**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[WCPM])
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /WCPM/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and Save this in Root Folder [WCPM] i.e. near Application Folder.

For More Details Refer the CI Manual @ http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite module in apache.

If that doesnt work or mod_rewrite is already enabled, try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change following `setting` in your `config` file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and then, replace `.htaccess` file located at your project root folder not in the application folder with the following code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: if it does not then check..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2

Answer (score 0):

There is a full article for this at:

http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/#remove-index-php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|imgs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^media/imatges/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).jpg?$ imgs/$1  [T=image/jpeg,L]
<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

This is the entire recommended code to put at the start of your .htaccess file