# Unable to remove index.php from Codeigniter URl

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am unable to remove index.php from my project Url. Below is the code i had try for that.

Below same code and config setting working properly for my another project hosted on same server

**In .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|imgs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^media/images/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).jpg?$ imgs/$1  [T=image/jpeg,L]
<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

.htaccess file is placed parallel to application folder and under root folder.

**In config.php file**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
(also tried same for all server global mentioned in config.php)

and

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**current project url is like `http://Hostname/ODP/` (this one not working for above code)**

**previous project url is `http://Hostname/WCP/` (this one working for above code)**

Comment: did you create a seperate vhost for each project?

Comment: Sorry but i am unaware of term vhost.. sounds like virtual host..how can it will solve above issue?

Comment: what is the base_url set to in the config?

Comment: ("http://hostname/ODP/") is set as base_url

Comment: try `http://hostname/ODP/` as base_url, please try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2?rq=1

Comment: That was same just written as link

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /ODP/` after `RewriteEngine on` in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Adding RewriteBase /ODP/ doesn’t resolves issue

Answer (score 0):

```
Use following htaccess code to remove index.php from your codeigniter url
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```