# How to redirect index.php with CodeIgniter being a subpage

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I am new the CodeIgniter and the index.php is being a pain in the ass.

I want some friendly URLs but my website is in a subfolder.

I installed the clean CodeIgniter installation, added another view for test purposes and this is what I am getting.

```
Page 1
http://www.example.com/webadmintest/
http://www.example.com/webadmintest/index.php/welcome/index

Page 2
http://www.example.com/webadmintest/index.php/welcome/byebye
```

This works perfect.

Now in the config file I changed to this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And added this in the .htacces in the application folder(I don't know if this is the place or the root CodeIgniter folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I stil can load the previous links but if I try to go to this ones it send me to the main www.example.com page.

```
 Page 1
    http://www.example.com/webadmintest/
    http://www.example.com/webadmintest/welcome/index

 Page 2
 http://www.example.com/webadmintest/welcome/byebye
```

I have also tried using:

```
$config['base_url'] = '/webadmin/';
```

and

```
RewriteBase /webadmintest/
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webadmintest/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

As you can see this is not the typical problem, I mean probably if this was a standalone website I probably wont have this problem, but the requirements need the website to be a subfolder of a main website.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Comment: You want to remove the file index.php or you just want it removed from the URLs?

Comment: I want it removed from the URLs

Comment: I have tried the piece of code in kumar_v's answer and in someway it is working.

My main page loads through this two links

`www.example.com/backend/`
`www.example.com/backend/main/`

But a second page throud this ones doesn't load

`www.example.com/backend/clients`
`www.example.com/backend/clients/index`

and it used to load as 
`www.example.com/backend/index.php/clients/index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

This applies to everyone who has the CodeIgniter in a subfolder

First of all the \subfolder\application\config\config.php

You have to find these lines and change it with these:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/subfolder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Next you have to modify your \subdfolder\application.htaccess with this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And then create a new .htaccess in \subfolder.htaccess and add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks to @saurabh2836 adn @Robin Morgan

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have the mod_rewrite in your, if not [Get mod_rewrite here](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750)

In the app folder > config folder > config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; -> $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: I did that and still no go.

Comment: I installed CI in a new folder and made all from scratch and nothing happened.