# Remove "index.php" from Codeigniter .htacceess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, frameworks, subdomain

I've been working in Codeigniter for a few days now & everything is going very well, accept I cant for the life of me get rid of the index.php in the url (from localhost/index.php/controller to localhost/controller).

I'm using CIs default index.php.

rewrite is enabled in apache.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

(Though I've tried the other four settings for URI)

.htaccess looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  <Files "index.php">
    AcceptPathInfo On
  </Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've tried the answers 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path/1445432#1445432)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

help would be wonderful

Thank you

P.S.
I'm working in a sub-domain if that matters.

Comment: You wrote `indew` instead of `index` - could this be your problem?

Comment: Typo in my post but not the actual file, I checked but thank you

Comment: where is your CI installed?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If the above lines don't work then you need to open your CI config file application/config/config.php

In that find the following line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Change that to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

If that does not work either then try changing uri_protocol to auto in config:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: I did all that, (look at what I posted above).

Still not working

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess this could be a problem
  `RewriteCond $1 !^(indew\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`
and make sure that that the rewrite module is enabled [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Or for the RewriteRule line, try changing it to this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

(the `/` before the index.php)

Comment: I just double checked, rewrite mod is enabled.

The typo was in my post not the actual file, but all the same I tried removing the line all together, still nothing...

Comment: Added another suggestion.