# Removing index.php from url [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

First of all pardon me for asking this question as it has been discussed in number of times.
I tried everything I came across but I feel I am doing something wrong. So I would appreciate some help in this case.

I want remove 'index.php' from urls. Currently the url is

```
http://localhost/eshop/index.php/home
```

But I want it like

```
http://localhost/eshop/home
```

[image: This is my folder structure]

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^\/(index\.php|res|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have also tried this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /eshop/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

With this only "`http://localhost/eshop/`" is working but "`http://localhost/eshop/home`" or "`http://localhost/eshop/contacts`" are still failing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Answer (score 1):

In addition you should say to your CI didn't insert index.php to generated urls

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

You also need to change config

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

There are several variant ( for exampl set index  page as empty string - see this topic  [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) )

Comment: I have this flag false. But it doesn't help.

Comment: try to set $config['index_page'] and $config['base_url']  as empty string

Answer (score 1):

make a .htaccess file in root folder of project and paste this code

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it always gives me 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

The following .htaccess should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```