# redirect on codeigniter is including index.php in the url and how to remove?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used redirect on my codeigniter project just after login page.

like

```
redirect('profile/edit/1');
```

and am seeing a url like

```
http://mypreoject.com/index.php/profile/edit/1
```

and , **my page background image was unable to load.**

i have used .htaccess mode write so this was not supposed to be happening and i should have get the following.

```
http://mypreoject.com/profile/edit/1
```

Comment: set site url in config page

Comment: @RakeshSharma  hey , i just did that this exceptionally case ok . all my htaccess has been setuped ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Comment: @Arun  hey this is expceptionmal case , itold u its not about removing index to the whole project ,but on redirects ,can u get that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CI controller -> action is working fine in both urls

> http://mypreoject.com/profile/edit/1
>
> http://mypreoject.com/index.php/profile/edit/1

then `.htacces` is fine, you should check `/application/config/config.php`  `index_page` key

change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: okay i got this $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and trying thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache place a .htaccess file in your root web directory containing the following:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`