# codeigniter url handling to remove index.php and method name

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

hi i am using codeigniter first time and i have to manage my URL to view URL without index.php/controller so how can i write ht access and where i keep it my folder structure as well as any other changes i have to do in my auto load or config file....

```
my URL is like below...
```

> **project_name/index.php/controller_name/method_name/param 1/param 2**

so for this URL how can i write ht access rule?please need helpful......

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```