# index.php not removing https CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

index.php is not removing while i use **https** but it works for http.
What I need to do is my site work properly such as it works on **http** and **https** both. Anybody faced same issue help me to fix this.

**Ex: In http**

1. http://xyz.mydomain.com/users/login  //works fine
2. http://xyz.mydomain.com/index.php/users/login  //works fine

**IN https**

1) https://xyz.mydomain.com/users/login **// 404 page not found**
  2) https://xyz.mydomain.com/index.php/users/login // works fine

**MY htaccess code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**config.php**
My base url is set as

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Comment: why not do `$config['index_page'] = '';` to remove the index.php inclusion in the first place?

Comment: first thing I'd do is check what `$config['base_url']` is set to after you do all of that. something like `print_r($config['base_url']); exit;`

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ''; is same as you wrote

Comment: what's the output of `$config['base_url']` in all 4 of your test cases?

Comment: prefix **http://** http://xyz.mydomain.com/ while i use without https and with https i print 
https://xyz.mydomain.com/ prefix **https://**

Comment: You should check if mod_rewrite is enabled for https, also check the `AllowOveride` permissions .  Check with your provider or system administrator.  This is a server setting issue. The .htaccess is fine.  You can also move the mod rewrite to the vhost.conf and ssl.conf.

Comment: @Deepaksharma Is this in your local server or live server ??

Comment: it is  in live server @abdulla

Comment: reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160217/codeigniter-url-handling-to-remove-index-php-and-method-name/29179617#29179617

Comment: @Deepaksharma check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35943979/4595675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there is a problem in your host file.
If you are using apache, change your host file like;

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   DocumentRoot /path
   ServerName xyz.mydomain.com
   ServerAlias www.xyz.mydomain.com

   SSLEngine On
   SSLOptions +StrictRequire
   SSLCertificateFile /path to ssl file/mydomain.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path to ssl file/mydomain.key
   SSLProtocol TLSv1
    <Directory "/path">
        Require all granted
        Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Now chnage your htaccess file like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: Thanks @sujeet Kumar in my vhost configuration following were missing **<Directory "/path">Require all granted
 Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI -Indexes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all </Directory> RewriteEngine On **  its working cool.