# remove index.php by using htaccess doesnt work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I would like to remove `index.php` by using `.htaccess` file in root directory.

my framwork is codeigniter .

my htaccess :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php

php_flag  log_errors on
php_flag  display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 8
php_value error_reporting E_ALL

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^megarooz.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://megarooz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

order allow,deny
allow from all
```

my config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://megarooz.com';


$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I got this message :

```
Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.
```

It doesnt work :

http://megarooz.com/admin/Admin/login

It works fine :

http://megarooz.com/index.php/admin/Admin/login

Comment: Is mod_rewrite installed and enabled in Apache? Also, try changing `on` to `On`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter URL rewrite to remove index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853184/codeigniter-url-rewrite-to-remove-index-php)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  how can I see `mod_rewrite` is enabled or not ?

Comment: What OS are you using? Btw, are you on PHP 5.3? You should _really_ upgrade your system. 5.3 hasn't been supported for a long time. Even 5.6 has reach end of active support.

Comment: my php version is `5.5.38`

Comment: **Question already answered** Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29179617/3635079

Answer (score 0):

Try doing using below code

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] // you have added / before index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

1.In  your root folder. `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2.In `application/config/config.php` set following things

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://megarooz.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an extremely commonly asked question on Stack I'd like you to some more research next time as it's filled with CI's index.php questions. Non the less I do agree with CI's htaccess being a little bad as it hasn't always worked for me either, what I end up doing is grabbing the htaccess from Laravel.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Never had problems with it, hope this will work.