# how to remove index.php in codeigntier ( ip address )

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

how to remove index.php

http://103.4.217.199/~xxxx/index.php/menu

to

http://103.4.217.199/~xxxx/menu

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Not working

Comment: This has been asked a few times on stack over flow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+remove+index.php+from+url+codeigniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Comment: These .htaccess might be able to help you https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running from an IP address type URL

**  -----------------------**

`<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~xxxx/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

Open `config.php` and do following replacement:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for `uri_protocol` does not work properly. Just replace:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

with

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Then use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thankyou i do it but not work 

Can remove index.php on case ip number ? 
i'm not sure do it

Comment: try using  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] this at last line of htaccess code

Answer (score 0):

this is my .htaccess that works on both wamp and live linux server running Centos + Apache  and Ubuntu +apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path-to-code-igniter-directory/index.php/$1 [L]

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I also made a video on how to do this here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-4VkR54vLU

(skip to 28:50 to see the .htaccess .I also put it in the description under the video)

hope that helps