# Codeigniter remove index.php from URL localhost:82/project

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

I have URL

> http://localhost:82/project/index.php/home

I want to remove index.php from above url.

> Like this : http://localhost:82/project/home

I have used many solution

1) I have remove index.php from config.php file :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

2) change "uri_protocol" in config.php file :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Anybody master here to solve my question ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you set `base_url` correctly? and default controller? what is the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this **Codeigniter** `.htaccess` file and install it to your root app.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Like this one...

```
project_name
    -application
    -assets
    -system
    -user_guide
    -.htaccess // like this one
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache Server, you must do `mod_rewrite` enabled. And then modify your .htaccess file with the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

For more information, visit [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

Try similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Try To Use This

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|admin|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|admin|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I use it and work on me.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Set your base URL in config as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:82/project/'
```

In your .htaccess, Try with this, I have used this in my CI projects.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Place this file in your project folder.

[image: Folder structure]