# .htaccess redirect rule same domain but different prefix

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, prefix

I need to redirect following url

```
admin.example.us
```

to

```
myadmin.example.us
```

I have tried different examples using `RewriteBase`, `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond`. Nothing quite fits my case and my regex seems to fail.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://myadmin.example.us%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my own solution finally was 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) myadmin.example.us/index.php/admin [L,R]
Neither seems to work atm since there's some other issue.

Comment: If you just copy-paste all and only my answer, it works. You can have problem to [enable mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Actually, when I started to see what's wrong, I found that the server is not on Apache - the problem is that Nginx doesn't use .htaccess files... my solution was to use AWS bucket and alias to redirect.