# htaccess remove parameter and index file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the proxy.php file and the parameter passed to it. This is what it looks like currently.

```
http://localhost/stuff/proxy.php?parameter=folder01/some.file
```

This is the way I would like it to look.

```
http://localhost/stuff/folder01/some.file
```

For my htaccess file, I have tried the following but they do not work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proxy.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

And this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /proxy.php?parameter=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try it in root dir or put this in stuff directory and remove `RewriteBase` line.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /stuff/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried in the root dir and in the stuff dir. Nothing changes when I visit the url.

Comment: Did you tried it in stuff directory, use this in stuff dir and remove `RewriteBase /stuff/`.

Comment: I moved htaccess to the stuff dir and removed the RewriteBase. Nothing happens still, which is weird. And I do have mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: Does rewrite mod_rewrite is enabled please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite are other rule working other than this?

Comment: I have tried it on my wamp server and a production server and mod_rewrite is enabled on both, but the htaccess you posted does not work on either of them