# Htaccess rewrite links doesn't work in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website and I tried to rewrite links using htaccess file but the rewrited link does not work. The original link is like this :

http://my-website.com/open?cours=3em-tricks

I want to rewrite it to this form:

http://my-website.com/tuto/cours/3em-tricks/

In the `.htaccess` file I write this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tuto/cours/(.*)$ open?cours=$1 [N]
```

But I always get the 404 page in rewrited link. Note the the htaccess module is activate on server.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean here? Have you tried turning on mod_rewrite logging to see what is happening?

Comment: i mean the new link won't works only the original one that works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the trailing slash and the `N`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tuto/cours/(.*)/?$ open?cours=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you replace te `[L]` with `[R,L]`, did you see the new URL?

Comment: same problem 404 notfound

Comment: Yes, but did you see the new URL?

Comment: I did not understand your question can you explain more

Comment: When you visit `http://my-website.com/tuto/cours/3em-tricks/` with your browser (and the flag `[R,L]` in the `.htaccess`), did you see the new URL (`http://my-website.com/open?cours=3em-tricks`)?

Comment: no  it stay like http://my-website.com/tuto/cours/3em-tricks  and get the 404 not found page

Comment: OK, so there is two options: 1. You have to [enable `mode_rewrite`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite). 2. Your `.htaccess` is not at the root of your website.

Comment: i'm sur that the mode_rewrite is enbaled and .htaccess is in the root  because im working with wordpress website and i have a rewerited url

Comment: My answer seem legit. You need to try something else, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/9632852/1737263.